# Can't perform a react state update error when using useEffect in a custom express route

Tags: reactjs, express, react-hooks

I have a problem with my custom express route. Every time I change page via my custom route component I get a react no-op error :
Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.

Here is my custom route component/handler :

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import { AuthenticationContext } from '../../contexts/authentication/context';

import Unauthorized from '../Unauthorized';

import axios from 'axios';

const ProtectedRoute = ({ component: Component, redirect: Redirect, contextProvider: ContextProvider, path, ...routeProps }) => {

  const { authenticationState: {isAuthenticated, isFetchingTheUser, currentUser} } = React.useContext(AuthenticationContext)

  const [authorized, setAuthorized] = React.useState(['Admin']);
  const [isFetchingAuthorizations, setIsFetchingAuthorizations] = React.useState(false);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useEffect from protected route")
    setIsFetchingAuthorizations(true);
    axios.get(`${global.REST_API_ADDR}/api/pages/${encodeURIComponent(path)}`)
    .then((response) => {
      setAuthorized(response.data.authorized);
      setIsFetchingAuthorizations(false);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      setIsFetchingAuthorizations(false);
      console.log("Protected route use Effect error : ", error);
    })
  }, [path])

  return (
    <Route {...routeProps}
      render={ props => {

        if(isFetchingTheUser || isFetchingAuthorizations) return <div>Chargement...</div>

        if(isAuthenticated && authorized.includes(currentUser.rank)){
          return ContextProvider ? <ContextProvider><Component {...props} /></ContextProvider> : <Component {...props} />
        }else if(isAuthenticated && !authorized.includes(currentUser.rank)) {
          return <Unauthorized {...props} />;
        }
        else{
          return <Redirect {...props}/>;
        }
    }}/>
  );

};

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

If delete the part with useEffect() I no longer receive a warning in the console, nevertheless I really need this hook to check that the user has permission to access this page

Can someone please enlighten me ?

Thanks in advance

EDIT 1 : 
I tried to create an empty component and accessed it via my same custom route (ProtectedRoute) and there is no warning, this "empty component" doesnt have any useEffect in it and it seems to be the problem in the others components... So I got this warning when I try to access a component with useEffect in it...

EDIT 2 : 
With further testing I can affirm with certitude that the problem is coming from the useEffect in my ProtectedRoute component, if i manually set the "authorized" array and the "isFetchingAuthorizations" it works fine. The problem seems to come from the setter in the http request (if I comment only the setters it works fine too...)

EDIT 3 : I added an useEffect in my empty component to fetch all my users and display it, and it throw a warning like all others components. I guess the problem comes from having an useEffect in the component...

EDIT 4 : I added a console.log in my empty component's useEffect, it seems that the useEffect is triggered even tho the component is not returned ! It might be the problem here !

EDIT 5 : The problems seems to come from the fact 'authorized' state is keeped between each routing, so when the user ask for a new route the 'autorized' state is filled with the previous page authorizations array... don't know how to fix it, i'm trying to empty it after the route has been served... if aynone have some tips

Answer (score 1):

I have one suggest for your case like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
   let didCancel = false; // to trigger handle clean up
   const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
          const result = await .get(`${global.REST_API_ADDR}/api/pages/${encodeURIComponent(path)}`);
          if (!didCancel) {
              setAuthorized(result...);
              setIsFetchingAuthorizations(result...);
          }
      } catch (error) {
          if (!didCancel) {
              setIsFetchingAuthorizations(result...);
          }
      }
   };
   fetchData()
   return {
      didCancel = true; // clean up useEffect
   }
})
```

Hope help you !

Comment: The return seems incorrect it throws an error, i changed it to 
return () => {
        didCancel = true;
      }; But i still got the no-op render warning...

Answer (score 0):

So here is what I think, you clean up your http requests before you unmount. I wrote something that might work for you, try it out and let me know. Also here is a helpful article on this https://medium.com/@selvaganesh93/how-to-clean-up-subscriptions-in-react-components-using-abortcontroller-72335f19b6f7

```
useEffect(() => {
    const CancelToken = axios.CancelToken;
    const source = CancelToken.source();

   setIsFetchingAuthorizations(true);
    const fetchData = axios.get(`${global.REST_API_ADDR}/api/pages/${encodeURIComponent(path)}`)
    .then((response) => {
      setAuthorized(response.data.authorized);
      setIsFetchingAuthorizations(false);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      setIsFetchingAuthorizations(false);
      console.log("Protected route use Effect error : ", error);
    })

    fetchData();
    return () => {
      source.cancel();
    };
  }, [path]);
```